# Second Run of same Method Fail

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Im calling method **StartNewGame** by clicking menu item and everything works fine until i click menu item again and yes i want it repeatable, i must have missed something :(

```
public Panel Gamepanel;
public TextBox Nazwagracza;

private void startNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartNewGame();
    }

void CreateNazwagracza()
    {
        Nazwagracza = new TextBox();
        Nazwagracza.Parent = Gamepanel;
        Nazwagracza.MaxLength = 15;
        Nazwagracza.Top = odstepgora;
        Nazwagracza.Width = 100;
        Nazwagracza.Height = 25;
        Nazwagracza.Left = Kalendarz.Left - Nazwagracza.Width - odsteplewo;
    }

void StartNewGame()
    {                      
        CreateGamepanel();
        CreateNazwagracza();
        Nazwagracza.Text = "Raz";

    }

int odstepgora = 10;
int odsteplewo = 10;

void CreateGamepanel()
    {
        Gamepanel = new Panel();
        Gamepanel.Top = odstepgora;
        Gamepanel.Left = odsteplewo;
        Gamepanel.Width = bgimage.Width - 20;
        Gamepanel.Height = bgimage.Height - 40;
        Gamepanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        Gamepanel.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        Gamepanel.Visible = true;
        Gamepanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        Gamepanel.Parent = bgimage;
    }
```

Maybe i should rewrite/clear all panel each time i call StartNewGame? what would be best way to do that? Any advices on improving above also welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Edited: Example what is not working is once set Text "Raz" in Nazwagracza.Text and said changed by user and then when u call StartNewGame again the Text Value dont change - strange.

Comment: What is problem here? What is not working? What is desired behavior by you design?

Comment: it is working until i call StartNewGame once more, but i want it repeatable and working. By not working for example i cannot change any field values like Text on TextBoxes created on this panel. U can change values until StartNewGame is called again :(

Comment: `it is working until i call StartNewGame once more` What does this mean? What goes wrong? What doesn't work?

Comment: U can change values until StartNewGame is called again :(

Comment: `U can change values until StartNewGame is called again` That is not an answer. What values are you talking about?

Comment: ive just checked and even when somehow dispose one of controls created on this Gamepanel its not recreated by StartNewGame Method but it should be created again am i right?

Comment: In simplest words i can. StartNewGame Method Executes only once, no matter how many Times i call it. I dont know why.